# Accidentally install ubuntu-desktop, how to get MATE back?

Tags: gnome, login, screen, mate

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 22.04.1 and I had a problem where my login screen disappeared so I tried to get it back by installing ubuntu-desktop. This brought the GUI back but also replaced MATE with Gnome which I definitely don't want. I reinstalled mate-desktop-environment and typed `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`  which game me

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/mate-session    50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-session   50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/mate-session    50        manual mode
```

I then tried typing 2 as the option and restarted with no joy.

What must I do to return to MATE?

Comment: You can select the window manager on the login screen. When you select Mate, does the system not boot?

Comment: Where on the Gnome login screen can you choose the DE? I've looked and I can't see it

Comment: You can have multiple DEsktops (DEs) installed (*I do and love them*), and have multiple WMs (*some DEs are WM agnostic, eg. LXDE & LXQt, others have a default - but allow it to be changed, some make it very difficult to change WM*), but the greeter is the DM being used. If you want the GNOME login, use `gdm3` as your DM, and select the desktop you want to use at login (*be it MATE, GNOME or something else that you have installed*)

Comment: I'm trying to get back to MATE at the moment and I can't find an option to change DEs anywhere on the Gnome login screen.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Comment: GDM3 is the GNOME Display Manager, which handles login.  After selecting my username, I see a GEAR icon at the bottom of the display which will let me change the session, be it *Ubuntu*, *Ubuntu on Xorg* or whatever else you have installed.  This is me doing it on a Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.(2) LTS [QA-test] install...   *This new install doesn't have any other options, but I'd expect them if I had added them, being a Quality Assurance install this install is default*

Comment: I can't install ubuntu-mate-desktop; cannot locate package. I tried adding ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/fresh-mate to my repo list but it still wouldn't work. I also uninstalled ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-desktop-minimal which did nothing. Finding the right packages is going to be a real pain so I think I'll be better off reinstalling.

Comment: If you can't re-install `ubuntu-mate-desktop`, as it's available for all *supported* releases of Ubuntu (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-mate-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) which include *jammy* or 22.04(.1), your last comment makes no sense, unless you've corrupted your sources.  I'd suggest returning to basics; ie. `sudo apt update` & read the output, any warnings, errors, or missing lines?  An `apt-cache policy ubuntu-mate-desktop` should show details without any PPAs required if using Ubuntu. We're limited to what you tell or show us.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall Gnome and install Mate. Then it should switch automatically.

Comment: How to do that? Please add more details.